# Express Js: If Else Statement only returns boolean

Tags: express, if-statement, boolean, block

I am stumped!

I am learning Express.js, all is going smoothly, but for some reason when I try and use an if else statement, the code block does not execute... I only get TRUE or FALSE. The condition is working just fine, but the code block for IF or Else just will not fire.

I am checking to see if a product exists within my JSON file based on the ID. If the product exists, it should return the product, if not I want to set a status error with a message... any insights would be appreciated.

I am using the app.get route to run the following

```
 const found = res.json(products.inventory.some(item => item.id === parseInt(req.params.id)));

if(found){
     res.json(products.inventory.filter(item => item.id === parseInt(req.params.id)));
}else{
    res.status(400).json({msg: "The requested Product cant be found!"});
}
```

Running http://localhost:5000/api/products/3 in Insomnia or the Browser results in the following:

*Its just True or False... no content*

[Insomnia Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WV77a.png)

Thank you for your time...

Comment: After some trouble shooting, it looks as if the problem is on line one... const found is returning a boolean value, and nothing else after it is running... any ideas why this is getting a response while simply saved as a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use `res.json` in this line:

```
const found = res.json(products.inventory.some(item => item.id === parseInt(req.params.id)));
```

The response has been sent to the client **already**. So you only receive the boolean value and the block after that doesn't execute.

You don't need `res.json` to check if the product exists.

```
const found = products.inventory.some(item => item.id === parseInt(req.params.id));
```

Comment: You can read more about `.json()` method from the Express documentation [here](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json)

Comment: Thank you very much, that of course worked! Appreciate your help!